# ExpressJS: req.body value comes as a string "[object Object]"

Tags: node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I'm trying to get multer working on my backend to be able to handle files.
I'm sending (POST) from an Angular 9+ Front-End a FormData Object to my backend that looks like:

```
foo: 'test',
bar: { id: 'someId', name: 'someName' },
file: { SOMEFILE }
```

On my back-end I've got a server.js file:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require("express");
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const app = express();

// SOME ROUTE IMPORTS -- Just the variable pointing to the route.


app.use(cors());

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.connect(uri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB Connection Error:'));

// THERE I "USE" THE PREVIOUSLY IMPORTED ROUTES: app.use(routeX);
```

and the route file in question (let's call it routeX):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const MIME_TYPE_MAP = {
    'image/png': 'png',
    'image/jpeg': 'jpeg',
    'image/jpg': 'jpg',
    'application/pdf': 'pdf'
}

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const isValid = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        let error = new Error("Invalid mimeType");
        if (isValid) {
            error = null;
        }
        cb(error, "docLibrary/equipment/");
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const dateNow = Date.now();
        const name = dateNow + '-' + file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('_') + '-' + file.fieldname;
        const ext = MIME_TYPE_MAP[file.mimetype];
        cb(null,name + '.' + ext)
    }
});

const upload = multer({storage: storage});
const cpUpload = upload.fields([{name: 'proforma', maxCount: 1}, {name: 'technicalDetails', maxCount: 1}]);

router.post('/newEquipment', cpUpload, async (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/';
    let receivedEquip = req.body;
    console.log('receivedEquip\n');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(receivedEquip));
    console.log('\n');
}
```

The problem is that the console.log functions gives me the following JSON for req.body:

```
"foo": 'test',
"bar": "[object Object]",
```

"bar" has become for some reason a String object that specifies the type of its value...
I get the feeling that it's because of multer and the fact that I'm sending a FormData but I'm not sure where to look at here...
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so it was pretty dumb afterall...
I'm not familiar with the FormData Object and by this point I wish there was a better way to send blob to the back end.
Not sure it exists, so for the moment, the workaround goes like this:

**ORIGIN OF THE PROBLEM:**

As mentioned by our good friend VSCode - a `FormData` doesn't accept an object as a value. Only `Blobs` and `strings`:

```
Argument of type '{ test: string; secondTest: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'test' does not exist in type 'Blob'.ts(2345)
```

**SOLUTION**

So all you have to do when appending to the `FormData` is stringify your `JSON Object`:

```
if (typeof currFormValue[key] === 'object') {
              const currObject = JSON.stringify(currFormValue[key])
              someFormDataObject.append(key, currObject);
            }
```

and on the server parse agains these fields to `JSON` like so:

```
Object.keys(req.body).map(reqKey => { if (reqKey === 'knowObject') { JSON.parse(req.body[reqKey]); } }
```

I'm sure there's a much better structure to work with out there but I know better than asking on SO which structure to use ;)

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try doing this;

```
router.post('/newEquipment', cpUpload, async (req, res, next) => {
const url = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/';
let receivedEquip = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
let uploadFile = req.files.file  // to get the file from the formData
console.log('receivedEquip\n');
console.log(receivedEquip);
console.log('\n');
```

});

Comment: I thought about it and actually tried it (didn’t work) but supposedly the body parser should be doing the job...